# Binary random number with a specific number of ones

Tags: algorithm, random, binary, language-agnostic, bitwise-operators

I am looking to randomly insert ones into a binary number where each specific set of bits has a fixed number of ones.
For example, if I have a 15 bit number, all 3 sets of 5 bits must have exactly 3 ones each. I need to generate say, 40 such unique binary numbers.

```py
import numpy as np
N = 15
K = 9 # K zeros, N-K ones
arr = np.array([0] * K + [1] * (N-K))
np.random.shuffle(arr)
```

This is something that I discovered, but the issue is, here, this solution means that it is not necessary that the ones are distributed in the way that I want - through this solution, all ones can be grouped together right at the beginning, such that the last set of 5 bits are all zeroes - and this is not what I'm looking for.

Also, this method does not guarantee that all combinations I have are unique.

Looking for any suggestions regarding this. Thank you!

Comment: I think you're going to have to explain this seeming contradiction a little better. *all 3 sets of 5 bits must have exactly 3 ones each.* contrasted with *the last set of 5 bits are all zeroes*.

Comment: Is the set of possible numbers reasonably small?

Comment: @john " the last set of 5 bits are all zeroes." is describing current, unwanted behaviour.

Comment: please note that the language tags are for quesitons specific to that language. Perhaps you dont care if its python or C++, but future readers that look for either of them, may find a python question with a C++ answer, and wont be happy about that.

Comment: Set ones in each group and shuffle each group separately. Remove duplicate results and replace them by newly generated numbers (this can theoretically create an infinite loop but should practically work).

Comment: I see that `(N-K)` is negative. What do you expect `[1] * (N-K)` to be?

Comment: if the langauges does not matter there are `algorithm` and `language-agnostic` tags

Comment: I have made a couple of edits. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, would this still work if the number of combinations I'm looking for is fairly large?

Comment: @Bathsheba, the final set would contain around 5000 numbers. The size of each of these would be around 50 bits.

Comment: @harjon: Might be feasible then to generate them all and shuffle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you could do something like this in Python:

```py
import random

def valgen():
    set_bits = [
        *random.sample(range(0, 5), 3),
        *random.sample(range(5, 10), 3),
        *random.sample(range(10, 15), 3),
    ]
    return sum(1<<i for i in set_bits)
```

i.e. sample three sets of integer values, without replacement, in each block and set those bits in the result.

if you want 40 unique values, I'd do:

```py
vals = {valgen() for _ in range(40)}
while len(vals) < 40:
    vals.add(valgen())
```

see the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) for why you should expect approx one duplicate per set of 40

Comment: this serves the purpose, thank you! I was wondering if this would still be an efficient method if the number of bits is more than 50, and the number of values I need is a multiple of 1000?

Comment: you could put a `print("duplicate found")` statement in the `while` loop to see when it's found duplicates.  this would show how many are getting rejected.  you've not been very precise what number your 50 is referring to.  in general you want to work out roughly how many possible combinations there are, then see how close this is to what you want to get back out.  when you want more than around half the total combinations you're almost certainly better off just generating everything and then returning an appropriate subset.  the birthday problem page describes this a bit